# Cookie sent from backend not being set on frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I have the following situation.

Part I:

- localhost:3000 is frontend (React)
- localhost:8000 is backend (Django)
- I make a successful cross-domain GET (I'm using django-cors-headers package)

Part of the response headers:

```
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=token; expires=Fri, 16-Feb-2018 10:56:00 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

- the cookie csrftoken is not being set in the browser (if I'm right, it's due to the browser ignoring cookies from a different domain), although I have it set to allow third-party cookies and site data (in Chrome's settings)
- POST fails due to csrf cookie not being set

Part II:

- I set the cookie manually
- everything works perfect

This is my ajax request:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
  }
});

jQuery.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {attr: value, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken},
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
})
```

Is there *any* way to read the cookie after the initial GET and set it in the browser?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue recently using django and angular 2, I had a problem with the configuration of django-cors-headers.

What is your django-cors-headers?
You can not set allow all and allow credentials at the same time.

This is not allowed:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Use instead:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3000',
    '127.0.0.1:3000'
)
```

[Set-Cookie response header not working using Angular 2 + django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579367/set-cookie-response-header-not-working-using-angular-2-django-rest-framework)

Comment: I have CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('localhost:3000', '127.0.0.1:3000') but it's not helping.

Comment: Ah, I got it... I didn't have this in my ajax call: xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to see the cookie in the **Response Headers** but not see them in the storage of the browser, the Issue might be related to the *Samesite* settings on the cookie. By default, django sets cookies with `Samesite=Lax`, which prevents cross-orign access of cookies.

on the cookie settings you can do this:

```
response.set_cookie('csrf_token', token, max_age=31449600, samesite=None, secure=False)
```

Please note that setting a cookie with `samesite=None` is dangerous and it should be set with `secure=True`, to ensure that cookies are only accessed on secure connections. But in this case, where you are on localhost, you can just set it up like that and make sure to change it for the production environment.

[The MDN Documentation on SameSite cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) gives more details on SameSite cookies.

In your `settings.py` file, you should also allow cross-origin requests by setting these:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://localhost:3000'
]
```

You should also ensure that you set `withCredentials: true` in your request.
Refer [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests) on how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Csrf is related to security … it validate that same browser is making the request
You dont have to set it in browser ( it’s happening by default )
If you want a quick solve you can disable csrf from backend
For more info about how to deal with scrf you can check
https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-csrf-validation-in-django-web-application/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29826663)