# Set cookies for cross origin requests

Tags: authentication, cookies, cors, http-headers, localhost

How to share cookies cross origin? More specifically, how to use the `Set-Cookie` header in combination with the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

Here's an explanation of my situation:

I am attempting to set a cookie for an API that is running on `localhost:4000` in a web app that is hosted on `localhost:3000`.

It seems I'm receiving the right response headers in the browser, but unfortunately they have no effect. These are the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: token=0d522ba17e130d6d19eb9c25b7ac58387b798639f81ffe75bd449afbc3cc715d6b038e426adeac3316f0511dc7fae3f7; Max-Age=86400; Domain=localhost:4000; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 19 Sep 2017 21:11:36 GMT; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 180
ETag: W/"b4-VNrmF4xNeHGeLrGehNZTQNwAaUQ"
Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2017 21:11:36 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Furthermore, I can see the cookie under `Response Cookies` when I inspect the traffic using the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools. Yet, I can't see a cookie being set in in the Application tab under `Storage/Cookies`. I don't see any CORS errors, so I assume I'm missing something else.

Any suggestions?

#### Update I:

I'm using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module in a React-Redux app to issue a request to a `/signin` endpoint on the server. For the server I use express.

Express server:

```
res.cookie('token', 'xxx-xxx-xxx', { maxAge: 86400000, httpOnly: true, domain: 'localhost:3000' })
```

Request in browser:

```
request.post({ uri: '/signin', json: { userName: 'userOne', password: '123456'}}, (err, response, body) => {
    // doing stuff
})
```

#### Update II:

I am setting request and response headers now like crazy now, making sure that they are present in both the request and the response. Below is a screenshot. Notice the headers `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Looking at the issue I found at [Axios's github](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/191#issuecomment-311069164), I'm under the impression that all required headers are now set. Yet, there's still no luck...

[image]

Comment: @PimHeijden take a look to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials maybe the use of withCredentials is what you need?

Comment: Ok you are using request and i think this is not the best choice, take a look to this post and the answer, axios i think could be usefull to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794895/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-in-react-redux

Comment: Thanks! I failed to notice that the `request` module is not meant for use in the browser. Axios seems to do a great job so far. I receive now both the header: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000` (used to enable CORS). This seems right but the `Set-Cookie` header doesnt do anything...

Comment: Same issue, but using directly Axios : https://stackoverflow.com/q/43002444/488666.
While `{ withCredentials: true }` is indeed required by Axios side, server headers have to be checked carefully as well (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231372/488666)

Comment: what server headers?

Comment: @PimHeijden any luck? Faced with similar problem. How did you solve it, please.

Comment: @1nstinct please read the accepted answer

Comment: I'm having the same issue here but with https protocol. Please check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76148572/cross-domain-httponly-cookie-not-being-set

Answer (score 423, accepted):

### Cross site approach

To allow receiving & sending cookies by a CORS request successfully, do the following.

**Back-end (server) HTTP header settings:**

- Set the HTTP header [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) value to `true`.
- Make sure the HTTP headers [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) and [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) are set. Don't use a wildcard `*`. When you set the allowed origin make sure to use the entire origin including the scheme, i.e. http is not same as https in CORS.

For more info on setting CORS in express js [read the docs here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options).

**Cookie settings:**
Cookie settings per Chrome and Firefox update in 2021:

- `SameSite=None`
- `Secure`

When doing `SameSite=None`, setting `Secure` is a requirement. See docs on [SameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) and on requirement of [Secure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#samesitenone_requires_secure). Also note that Chrome devtools now have improved filtering and highlighting of problems with cookies in the Network tab and Application tab.

**Front-end (client):** Set the [`XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) flag to `true`, this can be achieved in different ways depending on the request-response library used:

- [ES6 fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials) This is the preferred method for HTTP. Use `credentials: 'include'`.
- [jQuery 1.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7190487/2237467) Mentioned for legacy purposes. Use `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }`.
- [axios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543547/2237467) As an example of a popular NPM library. Use `withCredentials: true`.

### Proxy approach

Avoid having to do cross site (CORS) stuff altogether. You can achieve this with a proxy. Simply send all traffic to the same top level domain name and route using DNS (subdomain) and/or load balancing. With Nginx this is relatively little effort.

This approach is a perfect marriage with JAMStack. JAMStack dictates API and Webapp code to be completely decoupled by design. More and more users block 3rd party cookies. If API and Webapp can easily be served on the same host, the 3rd party problem (cross site / CORS) dissolves. Read about JAMStack [here](https://jamstack.org/) or [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/performance/what-is-jamstack/).

### Sidenote

It turned out that Chrome won't set the cookie if the domain contains a port. Setting it for `localhost` (without port) is not a problem. Many thanks to [Erwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2609980/erwin-rooijakkers) for this tip!

Comment: I think you have this problem just because of the `localhost` check this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1188145 and also this may help your case (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966861/how-to-correct-set-the-cookies-for-a-subdomain-in-jsp/50988268#50988268)

Comment: So you're refering to the remark that "the cookie domain must be omitted entirely"?

Comment: This answer helped me so much!  Took a long time to find it.  But I think the answer should mention that setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to an explicit domain, not just `"*"` is also required.  Then it would be the perfect answer

Comment: Thanks. Must that header be specific though? I'd like to assume a wildcard also works.

Comment: this is good answer, and all setup for CORS, headers, backend and front end, and avoiding localhost with override /etc/hosts locally with a real subdomain, still I see postman shows a SET-COOKIE in response headers but chrome debug does not show this in response headers and also the cookie isn't actually set in chrome. Any other ideas to check?

Comment: @bjm88 Did you end up figuring this out? I'm in the exact same situation. The cookie is set properly when connecting from localhost:3010 to localhost:5001 but does not work from localhost:3010 to fakeremote:5001 (which points to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file). It's the exact same when I host my server on a real server with a custom domain (connecting from localhost:3010 to mydomain.com). I've done all that's recommended in this answer and I tried lots of other things.

Comment: I don't see how those headers could be different in Postman vs. Chrome. It's the hostname that counts for the cookie — localhost vs. fakeremote.

Comment: @Form have spent a long time searching this; your experience is the same as mine - that the same hostname (different port) will send cookies, but different hostname + port will not. This seems to run counter to the withCredentials spec. Did you make any progress?!

Comment: Yes, thank you, the answer is here. I don't fully understand your question, but I'll try to answer it quickly. Cookies don't respect ports. Just leave out the port from the cookie domain. Port is not part of the domain concept anyway. In case of truly different domains, use a proxy if you can. That way you completely avoid the CORS problem to begin with.

Comment: @hagen Unfortunately I don't remember... but I did make it work in the end. I should have gone back to this answer as soon as I found the solution. Anyway, I know I had issues with OPTIONS pre-flight requests at the same time, which required modifications on my server. You might want to make sure everything is OK on that front!

Comment: In Angular, the required client side change is also to add withCredentials: true to the options passed to HttpClient.post, .get, options, etc.

Comment: The CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and the JS-API props "withCredentials/credentials" define if cookies are received/sent by requests/responses and the read/write access to cookies is still handled by the browser's same-origin policy. See also the post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46464563

Comment: In my case, I had to add the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header to give the client access to the `Set-Cookie` header. Here's a more in-depth description of what led me to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821342/8479303 .. Maybe I've misunderstood something -- but if not, hopefully it helps someone :)

Comment: @lennylip mentioned in his answer below, it is showing error for samesite and secure flag. Now secure flag will only work if we are operating over https. How to achieve this on local setup ?

Comment: Not entirely sure but it is starting to sound a lot like there is no way to achieve this anymore and we all have to start using proxies.

Comment: @PimHeijden if we use Allow-origin to * then i am getting this error has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Comment: Yes, that's expected. The  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header should not be a wildcard for 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' (credentials mode 'include' ) to work. Replace the wildcard with a specific host

Comment: I had success using the following `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` with value set to `Accept,Accept-Language,Content-Language,Content-Type,Authorization,Cookie,X-Requested-With,Origin,Host` (Maybe some are in excess, but it worked this way)

Comment: @Form we are facing the same issue. A cookie is not sent for other domains. Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @shwetap Actually as we were using the cookie for authentication purposes, we skirted the issue completely by using Basic Auth headers on all API requests instead (you can also use token-based auth with a "login" step if you want). In retrospect, that's a better design for an API anyway. We could only do that because we are in full control of the server itself, though. I suppose the "hope the browser sends the cross-origin cookie" approach is fraught with peril as cookies are under assault by tracking protection in modern browsers.

Comment: Hey, great answer! Help me save a lot of trouble while writing my app. May I suggest adding information if you are in development you should set secure to false in order to see cookie in browser? Later in production it should be changed to true of course

Comment: Yes sounds good, can you suggest an edit?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot, edit queue is full

Comment: and also I don't have enough reputation to suggest an edit :)

Comment: But wait a minute @marcin When doing `SameSite=None`, `Secure` is even required. The answer states this. By the way, `Secure` can't be false. It is either set or it isn't set. I suspect your problem is with the `SameSite=None` approach. You should be using a proxy, much simpler from the browser perspective. Standards around SameSite have recently changed and you can read about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite I intend to update my answer with the most recent standard but haven't got a lot of time for it.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you, when using `SameSite=None` you should be using `secure` flag, it is required when you read docs. However I spoke with couple of guys and in development without using proxy approach ( which I tried to avoid ) setting `Secure` flag to true just won't save cookie in browser, instead you can change it to `Secure: false` and cookie appears in browser. Later when you post your app to server so everybody can use it you should change to true for security reasons :) Cheers!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but as a consequence of standard change, new versions of Chrome do not work like that anymore. Why? "SameSite=None" only results in cookies being send cross site when "Secure". Such are the default settings of Chrome nowadays. Hence the line in my answer: "When doing SameSite=None, Secure is even required." Ill change the line where it says it is recommended.

Comment: I'm using latest version of chrome, and when I had `SameSite: None` with `Secure:true` cookie did not appear. When I changed it to `Secure:false` I have finally received cookie from my nodejs server

Comment: @Pim What I wrote is based on my experience in displaying  cookies in browser :) cheers!

Comment: Hi @Marcin Setting a cookie ("Set-Cookie") is one thing. Sending the cookie back the server is another. Was your cookie also sent ("Cookie") back to the server?

Comment: I've tried only to send from server to display in broswer while logging in.

Comment: In next couple of days I'll probably start to send my cookie back to server to detect if user is logged in etc

Comment: If you use subdomain for BE and FE, you should set domain for Cookie to ".example.com" (root domain) for subdomain service can access cookies that other subdomains created.

Comment: I wrote this code in server.js:

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, multipart/form-data");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5000");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.cookie("cookie" , "value" , {sameSite: 'none' , secure : true})
    next();
  });

Still didn't work out for me . I also tried res.setHeader instead of res.cookie butdidn't worked . Note : My front-end at port 3000 and back end at port 5000

Comment: When I see my cookies in application tab they are all set to sameSite = "Lax" evenn after writing this code .

Comment: @Marcin Hello, did you end up getting everything to work?

Comment: @PimHeijden Hello, did you ever come to a conclusion as to how to resolve this?

Comment: hey @TheVisionary. I actually did, I followed Pim's answer, however I did set the Secure flag to be false, and this was the only situation when in development in order to "see" the cookie in the browser

Comment: @TheVisionary this is the way I did it. https://pastebin.com/yYJ4LrW9

Comment: @Marcin Is this being used in a production environment? Seems to be insecure (correct me if I'm wrong though)

Comment: @TheVisionary as I mentioned this is in DEVELOPMENT so you can "see" cookie in the browser and make sure everything works fine. When in production you should always set Secure flag to true.

Comment: @TheVisionary and of course you are right about it :)

Comment: I use an Apache server locally at port 81 (using a virtual host). No cookies are coming in with CORS, not with chrome, not with edge.

Comment: that must be frustrating

Comment: This answer has multiple issues.  1) Cookie SameSite attribute only applies to sending cookies in CORS request, not setting cookies in CORS response. 2) For sending cookies in CORS request, the server does not need to set Access-Control-Allow-Headers, only Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is enough.

Comment: Hi @FishMonitor, Thanks for the comments. Sounds like you could be right. Can you suggest an update by simply editing the answer? I'll review it

Comment: The proxy thing helped me. My cookie was not getting saved into the storage , after i set proxy i could use both strict or lax and didn't need https which was necesasary for none-secure

Comment: I'm having the same issue here but with https protocol. Please check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76148572/cross-domain-httponly-cookie-not-being-set

Comment: Cool thing is that create-react-app has built-in support for proxying backend, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: This answer saves my day to send session cookies from the server (.net web api) to the client and vice versa. Both are hosting on different domain (cross-site). Thank you a lot !!!!

Answer (score 38):

Note for Chrome Browser released in 2020.

> A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site
> requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

So if your backend server does not set SameSite=None, Chrome will use SameSite=Lax by default and will not use this cookie with { withCredentials: true } requests.

More info https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site.

Firefox and Edge developers also want to release this feature in the future.

Spec found here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-01#page-8

Comment: providing samesite=none and secure flag require HTTPS. How to achieve this in a local system where HTTPS is not an option? can we bypass somehow?

Comment: @nirmalpatel Just remove the "Lax" value in Chome dev console.

Comment: @LennyLip I think that if you remove the "Lax" value, it actually still defaults to `Lax`, not `None`. (According to https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/, and also MDN.)

Comment: @nirmalpatel Just a note, you can have HTTPS on a local system with Let's Encrypt certificates. Look them up if they are needed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here but with https protocol. Please check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76148572/cross-domain-httponly-cookie-not-being-set

Answer (score 21):

In order for the client to be able to read cookies from cross-origin requests, you need to have:

1. All responses from the server need to have the following in their header:

   `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
2. The client needs to send all requests with `withCredentials: true` option

In my implementation with Angular 7 and Spring Boot, I achieved that with the following:

---

**Server-side:**

```js
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://my-cross-origin-url.com", allowCredentials = "true")
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/something")
public class SomethingController {
  ...
}
```

The `origins = "http://my-cross-origin-url.com"` part will add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-cross-origin-url.com` to every server's response header

The `allowCredentials = "true"` part will add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` to every server's response header, which is what we need in order for the client to read the cookies

---

**Client-side:**

```js
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // send request with credential options in order to be able to read cross-origin cookies
        req = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });

        // return XSRF-TOKEN in each request's header (anti-CSRF security)
        const headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
        let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
        if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(headerName, token) });
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

With this class you actually inject additional stuff to all your request.

The first part `req = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });`, is what you need in order to send each request with `withCredentials: true` option. This practically means that an OPTION request will be send first, so that you get your cookies and the authorization token among them, before sending the actual POST/PUT/DELETE requests, which need this token attached to them (in the header), in order for the server to verify and execute the request.

The second part is the one that specifically handles an anti-CSRF token for all requests. Reads it from the cookie when needed and writes it in the header of every request.

The desired result is something like this:

[image: response]
[image: request]

Comment: what does this answer add to the existing one?

Comment: An actual implementation. The reason I decided to post it, is that I spend a lot of time searching for the same issue and adding pieces together from various posts to realize it. It should be much easier for someone to do the same, having this post as a comparison.

Comment: Showing setting `allowCredentials = "true"` in the `@CrossOrigin` annotation helped me.

Comment: @lennylip mentioned in his answer above, it is showing error for samesite and secure flag. How to achieve that with localhost server without a secure flag.

Comment: just a tip here, angular default csrf interceptor implementation will not work, use this answer provided interceptor will work and it will attached cookie on GET calls too.

Answer (score 6):

For express, upgrade your express library to `4.17.1` which is the latest stable version. Then;

In CorsOption: Set `origin` to your localhost url or your frontend production url and `credentials` to `true`
e.g

```
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: config.get("origin"),
    credentials: true,
  };
```

I set my origin dynamically using [config npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config).

Then , in res.cookie:

For localhost: you do not need to set sameSite and secure option at all, you can set `httpOnly` to `true` for http cookie to prevent XSS attack and other useful [options](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html) depending on your use case.

For production environment, you need to set `sameSite` to `none` for cross-origin request and `secure` to `true`. Remember `sameSite` works with express latest version only as at now and latest chrome version only set cookie over `https`, thus the need for secure option.

Here is how I made mine dynamic

```
 res
    .cookie("access_token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: app.get("env") === "development" ? true : "none",
      secure: app.get("env") === "development" ? false : true,
    })
```

Comment: For me SameSite not sameSite (with capital S)

Answer (score 4):

Pim's answer is very helpful. In my case, I have to use

```
Expires / Max-Age: "Session"
```

If it is a dateTime, even it is not expired, it still won't send the cookie to the backend:

```
Expires / Max-Age: "Thu, 21 May 2020 09:00:34 GMT"
```

Hope it is helpful for future people who may meet same issue.

Comment: For folks using other servers, this is definitely not required

Answer (score 2):

1. frontend

   ```
   `await axios.post(`your api`, data,{
       withCredentials:true,
   })
   await axios.get(`your api`,{
           withCredentials:true,
       });`
   ```
2. backend

   ```
   var  corsOptions  = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', //frontend url
    credentials: true}


   app.use(cors(corsOptions));
   const token=jwt.sign({_id:user_id},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn:"7d"});
   res.cookie("token",token,{httpOnly:true});



   hope it will work.
   ```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the latest chrome standard, if `CORS` requests to bring `cookies`, it must turn on `samesite = none` and `secure`, and the `back-end` domain name must turn on `HTTPS`,

Comment: Can't you include cookies for https call from an http site with SameSite=None without Secure

Answer (score 1):

After more then a day of trying all your suggestions and many more, I surrender.
Chrome just does not accept my cross domain cookies on localhost.
No errors, just silently ignored.
I want to have http only cookies to safer store a token.
So for localhost a proxy sounds like the best way around this. I haven't really tried that.

What I ended up doing, maybe it helps someone.

**Backend (node/express/typescript)**

set cookie as you normally would

```
res.status(200).cookie("token", token, cookieOptions)
```

make a work around for localhost

```
// if origin localhost
response.setHeader("X-Set-Cookie", response.getHeader("set-cookie") ?? "");
```

Allow x-set-cookie header in cors

```
app.use(cors({
    //...
    exposedHeaders: [
        "X-Set-Cookie",
        //... 
    ]
}));
```

**Frontend (Axios)**

On the Axios response
remove the domain= so it's defaulted.
split multiple cookies and store them locally.

```
// Localhost cookie work around
const xcookies = response.headers?.["x-set-cookie"];
if(xcookies !== undefined){
    xcookies
        .replace(/\s+Domain=[^=\s;]+;/g, "")
        .split(/,\s+(?=[^=\s]+=[^=\s]+)/)
        .forEach((cookie:string) => {
            document.cookie = cookie.trim();
    });
}
```

Not ideal, but I can move on with my life again.

In general this is just been made to complicated I think :-(

**Update my use case maybe we can resolve it?**

It's a heroku server with a custom domain.
According to this article that should be okay
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com

I made an isolated test case but still no joy.
I'm pretty sure I've seen it work in FireFox before but currently nothing seems to work, besides my nasty work around.

*Server Side*

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

app.get("/cors-cookie", (request: Request, response: Response) => {

    // http://localhost:3000
    console.log("origin", request.headers?.["origin"]);

    const headers = response.getHeaders();
    Object.keys(headers).forEach(x => {
        response.removeHeader(x);
        
        console.log("remove header ", x, headers[x]);
    });
    console.log("headers", response.getHeaders());

    const expiryOffset = 1*24*60*60*1000; // +1 day

    const cookieOptions:CookieOptions = {
        path: "/",
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: true,
        domain: "api.xxxx.nl",
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + expiryOffset)
    }

    return response
        .status(200)
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        .cookie("test-1", "_1_", cookieOptions)
        .cookie("test-2", "_2_", {...cookieOptions, ...{ httpOnly: false }})
        .cookie("test-3", "_3_", {...cookieOptions, ...{ domain: undefined }})
        .cookie("test-4", "_4_", {...cookieOptions, ...{ domain: undefined, httpOnly: false }})
        .cookie("test-5", "_5_", {...cookieOptions, ...{ domain: undefined, sameSite: "lax" }})
        .cookie("test-6", "_6_", {...cookieOptions, ...{ domain: undefined, httpOnly: false, sameSite: "lax" }})
        .cookie("test-7", "_7_", {...cookieOptions, ...{ domain: "localhost"}}) // Invalid domain
        .cookie("test-8", "_8_", {...cookieOptions, ...{ domain: ".localhost"}}) // Invalid domain
        .cookie("test-9", "_9_", {...cookieOptions, ...{ domain: "http://localhost:3000"}}) // Invalid domain
        .json({
            message: "cookie"
        });
});
```

*Client side*

```
const response = await axios("https://api.xxxx.nl/cors-cookie", {
    method: "get",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",                
    }
});
```

Which yields the following reponse

[image]

I see the cookies in the Network > request > cookies Tab.

But no cookies under Application > Storage > Cookies nor in document.cookie.

Comment: I think you can make this work with the regular "Set-Cookie" header

Comment: I would like to thinks so too but I couldn’t manage. 
Will post some details maybe someone else can tell me what I’m missing?

Comment: The `cookieOptions` variable is crucial here. What options does the cookie have? Besides this, your browser settings can also interfere dramatically.

Comment: @PimHeijden I've updated my post with an isolated case.

Comment: Try looking in the per request cookies sub tab of the network tab. There you get more information about why a cookie was or wasn't set.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is not possible to set cookies in cross origin requests as from `app.example.com` to `api.example.com` for all users.

> Note that cookies set in CORS responses are subject to normal
> third-party cookie policies. In the example above, the page is loaded
> from foo.example but the cookie on line 19 is sent by bar.other, and
> would thus not be saved if the user's browser is configured to reject
> all third-party cookies.
>
> Cookie in the request (line 10) may also be suppressed in normal
> third-party cookie policies. The enforced cookie policy may therefore
> nullify the capability described in this chapter, effectively
> preventing you from making credentialed requests whatsoever.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#third-party_cookies

Additionally, Google is currently set to phase out third-party cookies in Chrome by 2024. (see google)

Alternativ ideas are

1. Proxy calls to `api.example.com` through `app.example.com/api/`.
2. Add an iframe to `app.example.com` that loads a page from `api.example.com`. The iFrame page can set cookies and send requests to `api.example.com`. Pages on `app.example.com` can send messages to the iFrame via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).
3. Use an iFrame to set a cookie on the parent as `example.com`. Though I do not see an advantage to 2 as it is also needed to pass data (user credentials in case of a auth cookie) to the iFrame.
4. Instead of using an iFrame the client browser can be redirected to `api.example.com` to set a cookie.
5. Use an alternative to cookies to pass data. For example if an auth cookie is needed, set it on `app.example.com` and when calling `api.example.com`, pass the cookie data in a header. Though this is a bit less secure as you will need access to the cookie on the client and thus cannot use [HttpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#httponly).

Answer (score 0):

[Pim's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/10586805) is very helpful,
But here is an edge case I had gone through,

In my case even though I had set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to specific origins in BE , In FE I received it as `*` ; which was not allowed

The problem was, some other person handled the webserver setup,
in that, there was a config to set the `Access-Control-*` headers which was overriding my headers set from BE application

phew.. took a while to figure it out .

So, if there is mismatches in what you set and what you received, Check your web server configs also.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help
for me regarding the sameSite property, after enabling CORS I also add "CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.None"
to the CookieAuthenticationOptions in the Startup file

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
.....
CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
.....
}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30602736)

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to "Lode Michels" from above regarding CORS cookie with the Heroku server, (and for other cloud providers, like AWS)

The reason your CORS cookie can't be set is because Heroku strip down SSL certificate at Load Balancer, so when you try to set the "secure" cookie at the server, it fails since it's no longer from the secure connection.

You can explicitally specify if the connection is secure, rather than the cookie module examining request.
https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies

with koa, add this:

```
ctx.cookies.secure = true;
```

---

edit: I can't comment on that answer directly due to lower than 50 reputation

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

In the backend

## Set credentials to true in your corsOptions:

```
const corsOptions = {
 credentials: true,
  };
```

## Set cookies before sending requests:

```
res.cookie('token', 'xxx-xxx-xxx', { 
maxAge: 24*60*60*1000, httpOnly: true, 
SameSite:"None" })
```

In the frontend

## Request in browser (using axios):

```
axios.post('uri/signin', 
JSON.stringify({ username: 'userOne', 
password: '123456'}),. 
{withCredentials:true})
.the(result 
=>console.log(result?.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to awesome answers above I'd like to offer alternatives. Generally cross-origin cookies is hard especially if you use it for authentication. So my suggestion would be to use proxy. Basically just a proxy to make your backend and frontend lookslike coming from the same host. You can use reverse proxy from loadbalancer that you're using e.g. Nginx, httpd, etc.

**Bonus**: If you're using Netlify you can use their rewrites and proxy feature to make it work.

For example, as hobbyist I want to develop things cheaply so I use the free version of Fly.io and Netlify for backend and frontend respectively. So to make everything appears coming from the same host, in the Netlify (frontend) I setup the following to avoid cross origin cookies.

```
# netlify.toml
[[redirects]]
from = "/api/*"
to = "https://yourbackend.fly.dev/:splat"
status = 200
force = true
headers = {Origin = "https://yourfrontend.netlify.app"}


[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 20
```

Hope it useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Backend code :

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "http://localhost:8080",
      "http://localhost:4200",
    ],
  })
);
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res
    .cookie("access_token", "token", { httpOnly: true })
    .status(200)
    .json({ message: "Cookie set!" });
});
```

Frontend code:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: "sreesha",
    }),
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json);
};
```

Dont forget to set credentials:include in frontend . Even if you set cookie in response, without credentials include ,cookie will not be set in browser