# How to correct set the cookies for a subdomain in JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies

I have the following setup:

- all the requests are https (I will just omit this in the following description)
- 3 docker servers: localhost:8090, localhost:8091, localhost:8092
- in hosts (on my windows machine) I have 3 domains: loc.localdomain, loc2.localdomain and loc3.localdomain all pointing to my IP address
- so I will use the localhost:8090 -> loc.localdomain, localhost:8091 -> loc2.localdomain and localhost:8092 -> loc3.localdomain in my apps

Now I have an app on `loc` that sets some cookies for `loc3` subdomain. I see that the cookies are set (or suppose to be set) in chrome network response.

```
Set-Cookie: MY_COOKIE=YUMM; domain=loc3.localdomain; 
expires=Fri, 21-Jun-2019 10:48:58 GMT; path=/coolApp/bro
```

Then in app at `loc` I have a button that sends the user in another app at `loc2` that redirects the user to `loc3` at `loc3.localdomain:8092/coolApp/bro/something/more`. So at this point in time I should see the cookie(s) in the app request at `loc3`, but I don't.

Cookies setup:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
//facesContext.getExternalContext().addResponseCookie("TEST", "TEST", properties); tried this too 
//then in properties will be the maxAge, path and domain set

Cookie cookie = (Cookie) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap().get("MY_COOKIE");
if(cookie == null){
     cookie = new Cookie("MY_COOKIE", "YUMMM");
}

cookie.setMaxAge(31536000);
cookie.setPath("/coolApp/bro");
cookie.setDomain("loc3.localdomain"); // I've tried ".localdomain" too

HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Any idea what is wrong in this setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on this (https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) the domain should contain at least 2 dots so the answer is to use other alias for localhost to simulate my subdomains. Something like: `*.example.com`

After changing the domain all worked as anticipated.