# when inspect Chrome's developer tools can't see a cookie being set in Storage/Cookies?

Tags: javascript, java, http, spring-boot, axios

> spring boot Set-Cookie header, but i can not see the cookie in Storage/Cookies, another way still can not see anything, but when i post an request, it will be send by browser automatically, my main domin is m.example.com, my request domain is api.example, i also set withCredentials = true in axios, i also find some answers in stackoverflow, but it can not solve my problem

`document.cookie() // can not read JSESSIONID`

[set-cookie-header-has-no-effect-about-using-cookies-cors-including-for-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookie-header-has-no-effect-about-using-cookies-cors-including-for-local)

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Comment: Cookie is not a function. It is an attribute under document object. Try with document.cookie . For your reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: cookie setting httponly, it can not be printed by document.cookie