# Set-Cookie is not present in httpclient response

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, postman, angular-httpclient

I am trying to create a login page in angular and to save the cookie that is being created by our spring boot application

This is how we create the cookie in BE

```
val cookie = createCookie(jwtProperties.cookieName, token, expirySeconds,
                false, true, jwtProperties.cookieDomain, "/",
                "sample comment")
response.addCookie(cookie)
response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
response.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
response.writer.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(JwtGetDto(token)))
```

This is the angular request

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
const url = `${environment.api_url}/api/v1/auth/login`
return this._http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), { observe: 'response', headers: headers});
```

This is the response in browser

[image: Browser Response]

This is the response in Postman

[image: Postman Response]

i have tried to add `withCredentials:true` in angular request and still it didn't work

Comment: Can it be CORS related? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests

Comment: When i first set withCredentials:true it did give me some cors error but i fixed that i added the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and Access-Control-Allow-Origin and the request went fine but the set-cookie header was still missing

Comment: Can you check if it's present via `curl` or equivalent?

Comment: The Set-Cookie header is present in curl so i suppose the problem should be with the way i am making the angular request

Comment: Found the solution ?

Comment: I encountered a similar problem where chrome didn't save the cookie in the Application/Cookies Window. Many proposed solutions didn't work in my case.

What ended up working for me was to explicitly set the path of the cookie to root "/" in my Spring Boot Server Application. I thought that without setting the path the cookie would shop up only for the path of the request. Instead chrome simply didn't set the cookie at all, without any warning/error.

Subsequent requests to other routes also don't require the access-control related headers that @Pavllo and others suggests. At least for now.