# How can I store cookies on a local client that are returned from a local backend API?

Tags: reactjs, flask, cookies, session-cookies, flask-login

I have two applications that I am running locally. A React frontend and a Flask backend. The backend handles all of the OAuth authentication and provides a bunch of end-points for the front-end.

**React**: http://www.local-app.com:3000/
**Flask:** http://www.local-app.com/

If I post to the URL `http://www.local-app.com/v1/auth/login` I get this response data:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.local-app.com:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 03:13:04 GMT
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: remember_token=username|long_remember_token_here; Expires=Sat, 07-Nov-2020 03:13:04 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: session=long_session_token_here; Domain=.local-app.com; Expires=Mon, 09-Dec-2019 03:13:04 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/
Vary: Origin
```

This seems correct to me but the Cookie is never stored on the client no matter what I have tried.

Posting to `http://www.local-app.com/v1/auth/login` in postman works. The cookie is set and persisted across other end-points.

I think the problem lies with the cookie domain. I have tried setting a proxy and all sorts but nothing has worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the Flask Cors module overwriting my Nginx CORS configuration. Adding the following code to the Flask app solved the problem for me.

```
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

Thanks Selcuk for pointing me in the right direction.