# How to set cookies from one subdomain to another (Heroku, Nodejs, Angular)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I have my backend and front end hosted on Heroku, but they are on different domains - frontend.heroku-app.com and backend.heroku-app.com. Is it possible to set cookies from the backend to the frontend in some way?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests

Comment: I already have this implemented