# Servlet cookies work on postman windows app, but not in chrome nor the postman chrome extension

Tags: angular, servlets, cookies, postman

So I am working with Angular, Java servlet and postgresql trying to build a little login system. I would like to use cookie to store the user name and user password.

```
        String username = request.getParameter("name");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if(LoginInfoDAO.verifyuser(username, password)){
        String.valueOf(UserDAO.getUserByUsername(username).getUser_id()));
            Cookie c1 = new Cookie("userid",String.valueOf(UserDAO.getUserByUsername(username).getUser_id()));
            c1.setMaxAge(20);
            c1.setPath("/");
            c1.setDomain("localhost");
            response.addCookie(c1);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print(UserService.getUserJson(username));
        }
        else {
            response.setStatus(404);
        }
```

I was able to add the cookie and retrieve the stored data on the other servlet on the windows postman app but not in chrome nor the postman chrome extension.

```
    Cookie c[] = request.getCookies();
    int userid = Integer.parseInt(c[1].getValue());
    out.print(om.writeValueAsString(ReimbService.getTicketsByUserid(userid)));
```

please help, this is so weird

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue. Thank you for this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/8735121

To solve the issue (sending cookies across domains, you need to add

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

to your servlet, and add

```
{withCredentials: true}
```

to your front end call, like this:

```
 this.httpClient.post<User>(url,params,{withCredentials: true})
    .subscribe((val)=>{//do something with the response}
```