# Cookie not added into request header

Tags: cookies, cross-domain

Like to ask a CORS cookie question again, I have spent quite some time on this but cannot resolve it. 
Here is the situation.

I got a Backend api in nodejs(http://localhost:5000), and a React Frontend app(http://localhost:3000).
In Backend side, Cors setting is like this.

```
private initializeCors(){
    this.app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      next();
    });
  }
```

I have set `{ credentials: "include" }` in Fetch Api when login with username/password. 
Set-Cookie has been set in response and I can see it saved in browser.
Cookie is with the format "Authorize=TOKEN;HttpOnly;Max-Age=3600;"
[Cookie in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTo6c.png)

Then when route to another url and it cannot retrieve data from Backend with 401 exception.
Here is the code of the sequence call.

```
const credentialsInclude : "include" | "omit" | "same-origin" | undefined = "include";
function getAllPayments() {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: credentialsInclude
    };
    return fetch(apiUrls.GET_ALL_PAYMENTS, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);    
}
```

I can see the cookie not added into header.
[No cookie in header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LQMf.png)

I have followed the best answer of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests), but cannot get it work.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured out. The issue was not caused by the CORS settings. It caused by the Cookie itself. 
For my case, I need to add `Path=/;` into `Set-Cookie` in response headers. So that the cookie from response could be added to sequenced requests after successful login.