# Sending origin cookies in Cors not working with VideoJS

Tags: javascript, laravel, cookies, cross-domain, video.js

I have the following subdomains:

1. `stream.example.com`
2. `sub.example.com`

Both domains have SSL certificates and are valid.
I am using `videoJS 7.6.6` which has [http_streaming](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming) library.

On `sub.example.com` , there is a video tag which sets a dash manifest as source containing links to `stream.example.com`.VideoJS needs to include laravel cookies from `sub.example.com` when making a request to `stream.example.com` links but this is not happening and when i download the `HAR result` from developer console i see empty cookies in the request.

My VideoJS HTML

```
<video-js id="player" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered">
            <source src="data:application/dash+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,......." type="application/dash+xml" crossorigin="use-credentials">
        </video-js>
```

The mainifest is valid and it contains `stream.example.com` urls

VideoJS

```
player = window.player = videojs('player', {
            html5: {
                hls: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            },
            controls : true,
            fluid: true,
            controlBar: {
                children: ['playToggle', 'volumePanel', 'currentTimeDisplay', 'timeDivider', 'durationDisplay', 'progressControl', 'liveDisplay', 'seekToLive', 'remainingTimeDisplay', 'customControlSpacer', 'playbackRateMenuButton', 'chaptersButton', 'descriptionsButton', 'subsCapsButton', 'audioTrackButton', 'settingMenuButton', 'qualitySelector','fullscreenToggle']
            },
            preload : 'auto',
            poster : '',
        });
        player.hotkeys({
            volumeStep: 0.1,
            seekStep: 5,
            alwaysCaptureHotkeys: true
        });

        var myplugin = window.myplugin = player.myplugin();
    }(window, window.videojs));
```

`stream.example.com` has the following headers when i view a video link in a browser tab.

```
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-credentials: 1
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization,Range
access-control-allow-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: https://sub.example.com
access-control-max-age: 86400
cache-control: private, max-age=18350
content-length: 69688791
content-range: bytes 0-69688790/69688791
content-type: video/mp4
```

I downloaded the HAR request to see how videoJS is making the request

```
  {
    "startedDateTime": "2020-03-15T07:53:57.647Z",
    "time": 1.1023430000004737,
    "request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://stream.example.com/s/......",
      "httpVersion": "",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Referer",
          "value": "https://sub.example.com/"
        },
        {
          "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
          "value": "empty"
        },
        {
          "name": "User-Agent",
          "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36"
        },
        {
          "name": "DNT",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Range",
          "value": "bytes=741-2044"
        }
      ],
      "queryString": [
        {
          "name": "u",
          "value": "....."
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [], // <-- The cookies are EMPTY
      "headersSize": -1,
      "bodySize": 0
    },
```

**Edit 1**

I am already sharing cookies in laravel by adding the following in .env

`SESSION_DOMAIN = .example.com`

The cookie domain for `sub.example.com` show `.example.com` but no cookie for `stream.example.com`

**Edit 2**

The response to videojs options request for `stream.example.com` are shown below

```
HTTP/2 204 No Content
server: nginx
cache-control: no-cache, private
date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 06:19:26 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: https://sub.example.com
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization,Range
access-control-allow-credentials: 1
access-control-max-age: 86400
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImM4czZNVFRRbWF1emFONXlVMjBGWkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiazVDMUNIR2NqXC9QVUpJdjA3S2lHQ2pKdkJFeHpZdGVodHQ5XC9nZ3JHYVQyUk50V2cxdkQrZ1wvV3ZsOEpDVUhBSiIsIm1hYyI6IjUwYjk4ZjYyZDJmNjg1ZjU4YTg2MDE5ZGNkYmZlOTk5NWVmNTE5ZTRjY2Q1YzQ0ZDI3MzEyNWQ0YmExMzVjZGIifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sat, 21-Mar-2020 10:19:26 GMT; Max-Age=14400; path=/; domain=.example.com
set-cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkZvZk9vK2J3YVVhQ2Q4VXpTZjZXN3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNHZId3orR3dQRDRiOXVFVitKR21NU21DbnVFXC9IcFMxaDFsUXRRUG9VQkFHZnNSdVpRSFBaaHJ5cXdGZDJObUgiLCJtYWMiOiI5ZjllY2IwZjFiNzkxYWMxNTI2ZTFiZWU5OTA4YjNjNzIxZWNkMTBiZjY0ZWQzNDBkMzg5MTEzYjM2MjQ4ODk1In0%3D; path=/; domain=.example.com
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you need to make the cookies **valid for all subdomains**, ***"share"*** them, as described [how to share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain):

> if you use the following, it will be usable on both domains:
>
> `Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=example.com`

Try an **OPTIONS request** to "url": "stream.example.com/s......" and see if you get the correct response cors headers as above? You can edit and resend the request through Firefox Developer tools.

All other look good.

- [Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests)

Comment: If i manually open the failed xhr in a new tab i see cookies with `.example.com` domain

Comment: @user2650277 it can be the options used html5: hls ... are for the previous version, try as here https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/5945  set withCredentials inside sources option.

Comment: Same here: https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming#withcredentials

Comment: i also already adding `withCredentials` as initialization option but its didn't work

Comment: I think you use the documentation of version 5, Version 7 says you should do: player.src({ withCredentials: true
});

Comment: Try an OPTIONS request to "url": "https://stream.example.com/s/......" and see if you get the correct response cors headers as above? You can edit and resend the request through Firefox Developer tools.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of all the cookies settings from Developer tools? try to click on the cookie and copy its Data.

Comment: my main domain is `example.com` and on `sub.example.com` i see both request and response cookies.I see request cookies on `stream.example.com` if i view the url in a new tab.Via VideoJS (XHR) there is no cookies in the request for `stream.example.com`. The fact that i see cookies on `sub.example.com` show that cookies are correctly setup in laravel

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can do this now:

```
const player = videojs(element, options)
player.crossOrigin('anonymous')
```