# Set-Cookie header not working across domain

Tags: http, cookies, cors, cross-domain

I am on a website `https://aaa.shared.com`. This website (call it `A`) sends an `xhr` request to url `https://zzz.shared.com/some/path` (website `Z`) and receives a response with the following headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: aaa.shared.com
set-cookie: foo=bar; expires=Fri, 01 Jan 2100 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
```

(I followed [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests) to add `access-control` headers)

Now, what I would expect is that whenever I am on both A or Z, whenever a request goes **to Z** (cross-origin or same-origin, what matters is URL of the request) browser would add the cookie, but it doesn't! Moreover, I cannot see it being set in browser Developer Tools (F12 -> Application -> Cookies). I am using Chrome, but aiming for a cross browser solution.

What am I missing? I am finding it really hard to find some elaborate information on how `Set-Cookie` header works when requesting a different origin.

EDIT: `rowan_z` originally suggested to replace `samesite=lax` to `samesite=none`, as A and Z in the first version of this question were completely separate domains (shared only `.com` part). I tried it and it didn't help. But now I realise that they are actually regarded as `SameSite`, because they are on the different subdomains of `shared.com` domain. So now I believe that `samesite=lax` should have worked here as well.

UPDATE:
In the end, I just moved the application `aaa.shared.com` under same subdomain with some path `zzz.shared.com/aaa/path`, as dealing with cookies and CORS is really tough. Also, configuring it to work with `localhost` adds extra complications.

Comment: Set the cookie`s domain to "shared.com", as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60730433/4448410 You are not setting the Domain property at all, so by default it may be set to "aaa.shared.com"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the things you did are indeed **required** to make it work:

- `access-control-allow-credentials: true`
- `access-control-allow-origin: aaa.shared.com` (not a wildcard)
- `Secure`
- `SameSite=None`

You were just missing one thing when sending the request: [credentials: 'include'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials).

I've created a mock endpoint that you can use to test this line of code twice (in the console of another domain):

```
fetch('https://stackoverflow.free.beeceptor.com', { credentials: 'include' });
```

You'll notice the cookie will be sent the second time.

In case the mock endpoint expires (no idea how long it lasts), or if someone destroys it, you can recreate it on http://beeceptor.com with this JSON in the header configuration:

```
{
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Set-Cookie": "test=value; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None;",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "https://yourdomain",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Another bit I had to figure out myself was that browser actually sends an `OPTIONS` request for a `GET` in this case (I assume this is because we ask for credentials). And Chrome recently made `OPTIONS` requests not visible in the Dev Tools anymore, so the error I was getting was a bit misleading, as it seemed to be complaining about a `GET` response when in reality it was complaining about OPTIONS request. Realising that, I just reenabled `OPTIONS` request trace following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410051/chrome-not-showing-options-requests-in-network-tab)

Comment: Yes the `OPTIONS` is because the cookie makes the request "non simple" (this is a term from the HTTP spec) and that triggers a preflight request to check if the endpoint actually accepts the request we are about to send. This is explained pretty clearly here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly stated `SameSite=Lax` which restricts cookies from being sent on cross-site requests. This looks like a situation where you want `SameSite=None` to allow those cookies.

More detail on: https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained

Comment: hi, thanks, good spot. I added `samesite=none` as in your great article. Unfortunatelly it doesn't seem to solve the problem for me. The cookie is still not set and not sent

Comment: Any ideas what else might be going on here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Actually, this might be even more interesting, I have updated the question. My domain A and domain Z probably are `SameSite`, because look like `xxx.sss.com` and `yyy.sss.com` (they are subdomains of the same `sss.com` domain`)