# Cannot save cookie in express-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, cookies

I'm creating a small MERN app for signup, login and after successful login, it shows their profile.

**1.** I want the user to log-in and if it's successful I will send the user._id to the react app and redirect it to profile/user._id

**2.** At the profile page in the ComponentDidMount method, I will do a get-request to get the user-data from my server using it's user._id.

**3.** In this get-request, I want to check if this user has an active session or not so that even if someone uses an URL: profile/some_user_id it will always check for an active session.

**My question is:**

**1.** Do I need to explicitly send the cookie to the client if yes then how or express-session will do it for me.

**2.** After the solution to **1** how can I access this saved data int\ the session when I do /profile/id get-request.

My app.js

```
require('./passport')(passport);

app.use(cookieParser());
//Express session
app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'secret',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { maxAge: 60*60*1000 },
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(203).send(err);
        } else {
            if(user) {
                req.login(user, err => {
                    req.session.user = user;
                    console.log(req.session);
                    res.status(200).send(user._id);
                })
            } else {
                res.status(202).send(info);
            }
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    console.log(req.session);
    res.send("session is running");
})
```

My passport.js

```
passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password'}, (email, password, done) => {
            // Match User
            User.findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {
                    if(err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    if(!user) {
                        return done(null, false, { msg: 'Input data incorrect!'})
                    }
                    // Match Password
                    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                        if(err) throw error;
                        if(isMatch) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            return done(null, false, { msg: "Input data incorrect!"})
                        }
                    });
                })
        }) 
    );
    
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
      });
      
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
```

console.log(req.session) in the '/login' post request.

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2020-07-03T18:44:55.179Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  },
  passport: { user: '5ef7a8b55570c353bc1aef12' },
  user: {
    _id: 5ef7a8b55570c353bc1aef12,
    email: 'mukeshgupta202000@gmail.com',
    userName: 'asdd',
    password: '$2b$10$wzF6uwxcFNHgi4NdNBL5A.wEAs4W14zQ8YpEboPJWttvRaIO6MXCq',
    createdAt: 2020-06-27T20:14:45.303Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-06-27T20:14:45.303Z,
    __v: 0
  }
}
```

console.log(req.session)

console.log(req.session.user)
in the '/user/:id' getrequest.

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2020-07-03T18:44:57.514Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
}
undefined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After being stuck for a few days I got the solution.

**1.** No you don't need to explicitly send the cookie to your client but you need to save your user data on your own.

```
req.session.user = userLoggedIn;
```

**2.** And to access this userLoggedIn data in a different route you need to use the same object:

```
req.session.user
```

The reason the above code didn't work was because of CORS.

To make it work just you need to **explicitly** tell the cors() in your express app whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies and where to send the cookie.

This can be done by the following code:

Server-Side

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001',  //Your Client, do not write '*'
    credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Client-side (if using axios)

```
axios.method('url', data(if needed), {withCredentials: true})
```

This will tell the browser to send the cookie on each request.

For other request-response libraries visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/13603547).