# set cookie on a react app running on different port from express api server running on different port on same machine but not on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, https

I am running both the react app on 0.0.0.0:5000 and expressjs api server on 0.0.0.0:3000 .i.e. instead of accessing them via localhost I am using my machines ip on home network which is

192.168.0.7:5000 (for react app)
192.168.0.7:3000 (for api server)

I have to test this on different devices connected to my home wifi. However the app is unable to allow set cookie

**`this set cookie was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url`**

as per suggestions over net added `proxy` to package.json of react app

[image]

and in changed cookie domain in api server setting to **192.168.0.7:5000** (address for react app)

below is the screenshot of the network request in chrome

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests)