# Access cookie data outside a component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, next.js, apollo-client

I'm building a Next.js app using Strapi as a CMS and authentication server. I've managed to get a JWT from the auth endpoint, and have stored it in a cookie. To retrieve secured content from strapi I need to [send this JWT in the header](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/auth-request.html#login-as-a-reader)

I'm using Apollo to send graphQL queries to strapi, according to their [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#header), I can easily set auth headers by adding this to `utils/apollo.js`

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = cookies.get('jwt') <-- This is what I'd like to do, but I can't figure out how to access cookies at this point.
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});
```

**How can I access cookies in the app mentioned above. It's not part of a component, though it is used to build a HOC?**

While using localstorage is an option, I've read that cookies are a safer way to store data.
Using cookies with secure isn't an option - I'm not sure if strapi allows it, and also because there are multiple frontend origins vercel builds previews for all branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set the cookie it will be passed in the `Cookie` header so you need to retrieve it from there, not the `cookies` object which is only available in the browser but not available in server-side requests. In addition, if you're using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) you will need to [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/5863693) credentials both in the client and server, specifically in the client you need to set `credentials: 'include'`. This is required setting for cookies to work.