# cookies: send cookies from subdomain(1) server to subdomain(2) frontend but cookies are not getting set in the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, cross-browser

I am sending cookies from subdomain(1) express server to subdomain(2) react frontend with cookie domain set as actual domain.
cookies domain is set to my actual domain.

I can see cookies in the network panel, cookies are coming with the response.

I tested in postman, everything is working as expected but not in browser. Tried in firefox and chrome as well.

Comment: have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests

Answer (score 0):

So nothing worked. We could not figure out why cookies were not getting set.
We decided to set cookies manually using `js-cookie` lib.