# Cookie not being set locally with Express and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I have an ExpressJS app running at `localhost:8181` and a ReactJS running at `localhost:3000`. In my Express app I'm using `cookie-session` to generate a cookie. The Express app looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');

const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid')

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'shortlinks',
  keys: [process.env.SESHSECRET],
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 30 days
}))


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  req.session.id = (req.session.id || uuid());
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  next();
})

app.get(
  '/api/links',
  (req, res, next)=> {
    res.json(readDb());
    next();
  }
)
```

In my React app I'm making simple GET and POST requests to the Express app. They look like this:

```
export async function getLink(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`${LINKS_URL}/${id}`, { withCredentials: true, credentials: 'include' });
  const json = await response.json();
  return json;
}

export async function createLink(url) {
  if (!url) return;
  const response = await fetch(LINKS_URL, {
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ long_url: url })
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  return json;
}
```

In Chrome when I inspect the Network responses I see the cookie being set in the response headers:

```
Set-Cookie: shortlinks=eyJpZCI6IjkxNDg0MTFjLTI5MTAtNGQ5Ni04ZTdhLTZlMzAyZTQ4NzljNiJ9; path=/; expires=Sat, 21 Nov 2020 00:39:18 GMT; httponly
Set-Cookie: shortlinks.sig=kz0vL2oUQ9KYsDrROkLasxV762w; path=/; expires=Sat, 21 Nov 2020 00:39:18 GMT; httponly
X-Powered-By: Express
```

But when I inspect the cookies in Chrome under Application -> Storage -> Cookies, I do not see any cookies.

What I've tried so far (none of these worked):

- Accessing React via `127.0.0.1:3000` instead of `localhost:3000`
- Modifying `/etc/hosts` to map `localhost` to a generic `www.localexample.com` URL
- Modifying the `fetch`s in my React App (adding/removing/changing the `credentials` and `withCredentials` parameters)
- Trying a different browser

What else can I try? I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/3809888). I added the header `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');` to my Express app and `credentials: 'include'` to my `fetch` requests, and I now see the cookie in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't the samesite be found with a warning in the cookie checked in the network tab?

Recently, browsers have introduced a new specification, samesite.

There are three options for samesite: Lax, None, and Strict.

Previously, None was the default, but now Lax is the default.

To give the None option, you need to communicate with https, and you may need to use SSL on the local host for this task.

For more information on Samesite, check out below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

[additionally]

- Support may vary by browser
- Check cookie domain - localhost or 127.0.0.1 [ with port ] : localhost and 127.0.0.1 are different.