# React Axios, Can't read the Set-Cookie header on axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, axios

I can't read the set-cookie header on the response object in axios, I'm posting user/password to backend and the response has the authorization cookie in the Set-Cookie header, however I can't see it on the res.header object, nevertheless if I go chrome dev tools and open the network tab I can see the cookie on the response header.

Any clue?

My post:
axios.post(
endPointLogin,
{ email, password },
{ withCredentials: true }
)

[The res object in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2w64.jpg)

[the header on chrome dev tools with the set cookie header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myHav.jpg)

```
export function login(email, password) {
  return http.post(
    endPointLogin,
    { email, password },
    { withCredentials: true }
  );
}

    const handleSignIn = async ( e ) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const respuesta = await login( cuenta.email, cuenta.password );
        console.log( "res:", respuesta );
    };
```

**Response:**

```
config: {url: "http://localhost:3000/usuario/auth", method: "post", data: "{"email":"admin@bmw.com","password":"admin"}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: "OK"
headers:
access-control-allow-credentials: "true"
access-control-allow-headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
access-control-allow-origin: "http://localhost:5000"
connection: "close"
content-length: "2"
content-type: "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
date: "Tue, 03 Nov 2020 15:00:46 GMT"
etag: "W/"2-nOO9QiTIwXgNtWtBJezz8kv3SLc""
vary: "Accept-Encoding"
x-powered-by: "Express"
__proto__: Object
request: XMLHttpRequest {__sentry_xhr__: {…}, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

**Response Header in google dev tools network tab **

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:5000
connection: close
content-length: 2
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 15:00:46 GMT
etag: W/"2-nOO9QiTIwXgNtWtBJezz8kv3SLc"
set-cookie: jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbXByZXNhIjoiYm13IiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBibXcuY29tIiwic2VndXJpZGFkIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2MDQ0MTU2NDZ9.CpIIScbZQCKsyxvc64CJ290fNCUlpKxZ5zBT3JK2tvc; Path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Comment: Hi, it will be very useful if you share with us the code that you are using, showing us how you are trying to access this header, a print or copy of your response and errors that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

As you have CORS in this request, you must [authorize headers to be read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests#:%7E:text=To%20allow%20receiving%20%26%20sending%20cookies,and%20not%20with%20a%20wildcard%20*%20.)
Also, cookie must be not 'httpOnly' but it seems to be the case
More about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#:%7E:text=Cross%2DOrigin%20Resource%20Sharing%20(CORS)%20is%20a%20mechanism%20that,resources%20from%20a%20different%20origin.)

Comment: Thank you!, I changed my set up to use a proxy in order to avoid CORS, I'm getting a lot more headers now. I still can't get the set-cookie so I think the problem is in the httpOnly as you pointed me.

Answer (score 0):

You can not read `Set-Cookie` header in JavaScript code, as mentioned in this **mdn** article.

Comment: Thanks, It's working now, my mistake was that I was trying to read the cookie to store it with the setCookie method and this is done by the browser.

Comment: @SebastianOrtega how do I send that cookie to server? login is ok and response is the same with you.

Comment: if you're in different domain just set withCredentials: true, if you're in the same just works

Comment: article link missing