# Authenticate and access spring security protected API from a react js application

Tags: reactjs, cookies, spring-security, axios

My objective is to access spring security protected API from a react js application after authentication.

- Spring boot application hosted at http://myserver:8080
- React JS application is hosted at http://myserver:3000

**I am able to authenticate and access the APIs using curl as follows:**

1. Access login url with credentials . Extract jsessionid token from response header.
2. Access end url with jsessionid token.

```
$ curl -i -X POST login_url --data 'username=myusername&password=mypassword'
$ curl end_url -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=session_token'
```

**I am trying to replicate the same through React JS Application.**

- Even though JSESSIONID Cookie is present in response header (verified through curl , and browser dev tools) but axios response header is not able to capture it.
- I understand that "Set-Cookie" header in JavaScript code will not work by default. As discussed in this question [React Axios, Can't read the Set-Cookie header on axios response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64652891/react-axios-cant-read-the-set-cookie-header-on-axios-response)
- Kindly help with modification required in code to achieve the same. OR suggest alternate way to achieve the objective.
  Thanks.

Client side code is as follows:

```
const onSubmitAuthenticateButton = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const loginUrl = 'http://myserver:8080/login';
 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
 axios.post(loginUrl, { username, password})
      .then(res => console.log(res.headers))
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
}
```

In Spring Secuirty configuration, csrf is disabled and cors allowed origin for "http://myserver:3000".

**WebSecurityConfig class**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;

    public WebSecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider) {
        super();
        this.customAuthProvider = customAuthProvider;
    }
        
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();           
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
        }
}
```

**WebMvcConfig class**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://myserver:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST")
                .exposedHeaders("Set-Cookie")
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS)
                .allowCredentials(true);       
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the objective through alternate way.
Instead of session based authentication, i am now using stateless authentication. Upon successful authentication a jwt token is returned as response. Subsequent API call, the jwt token is attached as payload. The application checks for the validity of token before processing the API call request.