# Cookies not being sent cross-domain

Tags: express, cookies

I'm trying to send access and refresh tokens from the server to the client and vice versa using http only cookies. The server sends the cookies to the client, but when the client makes subsequent requests, the cookies aren't sent to the server.

The client URL is [www.localtest.me:5173](http://www.localtest.me:5173)

The server URL is localtest2.me:8000

Following the answer mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67169371/httponly-cookies-in-cross-domain-requests-not-being-sent), I've set http only to be true, secure to be true, and same site to be none, but even then, the client is unable to send the cookies back to the server. (I've also set `withCredentials: true` in the axios instance)

So what am I doing wrong?

The response from the server on logging in:

[image]