# Session cookies working successfully in Postman, not Chrome

Tags: cookies, jwt, cross-domain, session-cookies, chromium

This is my first time messing around with session cookies and I'm having a pretty hard time. I'd really appreciate any help!

I'd like to note:

- I'm experiencing all of these issues locally on Chrome
- I have absolutely no issue receiving the cookie and authenticating the request using Postman. It's Chrome that doesn't set the cookie.

### The Server

My server is running on http://localhost:7000/

I'm sending cookies to the client from the server by setting the `Set-Cookie` header like so:

```
val cookie = """jwt=$token; Path=/; Domain=localhost; Max-Age=86400; Expires=Thu, 19 Aug 2021 12:20:23 GMT; SameSite=Strict;"""

ctx.header("Set-Cookie", cookie)
```

I also have cors set up:

```
it.header(Header.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true")
it.header(Header.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "*")
it.header(Header.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "*")
```

### The Front End

My F.E is running on http://localhost:3000/

Here's what an auth request/response looks like:
[image]

Here's what one of the failed requests looks like. Notice how there is no cookie set:
[image]

I've also noticed that the cookie does not show up in Chrome's `Cookies in use` view:
[image]

### My Understanding

From what I understand, I can use `SameSite=Strict` since both FE & BE are running locally on localhost.

When I move into production, FE & BE will not be on the same domain. Then, I'd have to use `SameSite=None; Strict`. Is this correct?

Also, I'm aware that I can also include `HttpOnly`, but I'm not at the moment for debugging purposes.

Is my understanding correct?

### Thanks!

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't properly setting `credentials: include`

Answer (score -2):

i suggest you try setting the allow-origin to * and check the result:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

it would allow request from any address, not secure but can help you find where the problem is coming from

Comment: Hi Erfan, thanks for the response. I've seen in [a few places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/15031707) comments about how allow origin should not be set to `*`, but I've just tried it for testing purposes:

Comment: `GET /api/transfers?limit=5&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7000
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
accept: application/json
DNT: 1
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
credentials: include
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9`