# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials in combination with httpOnly - cookies

Tags: cookies, cors

Through the header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" one can define that the response will be exposed and accessible to JavaScript.

[From the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials):

> Credentials are cookies, authorization headers, or TLS client certificates.

When using Cors - Cookies I need to set this header to true (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/6458608).

Through a "http-only" cookie I can define that a cookie should not be exposed in the JS - context.

This two configs are challenging each other, at least in my understanding.

Questions:

- Is there some priority like "a http-only is never exposed to the JS - context even when the allow-credentials header is set"?
- Do I need to consider something while using cors - cookies? Or can I tell for sure that I can never access a http-only - cookie in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

These two settings are related, but don't challenge each other. In the case of  `http-only` you are saying whether or not you'd ever have access to the *value* of the cookie in javascript.

On the other hand, the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is set by the server, to tell the browser whether javascript has the ability to tell the browser to send cookies on a `CORS` request (using the `withCredentials` flag on `xhr`). So, javascript would still not have access to the actual cookie values, it just now has a way to modify the browser behavior on when to send cookie values.

More information -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: This fits with the behaviour of the browser and some tests I have done to understand the concepts. In this case I find that the mozilla - documentation is a little bit misleading.