# CSRF token cookie is not set for cross origin requests

Tags: flask, cookies, axios, cross-domain, csrf

#### The problem:

In production my server and client are running in different origins (CORS).
The client needs to store a cookie sent from the server, but it fails to do so even that the cookie attributes are set as required.
The server is written in Flask and the client sends requests with Axios.

#### What I've tried so far and current status:

- First off, when the client and server are in the same origin (`localhost:3000` and `localhost:5000`) the cookie is set as expected
- To simulate CORS locally, I run the client in `127.0.0.1:3000` and the server in `localhost:5000`.
  The bug is reproduced in these settings.
- I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests) (and many others) and configured the server, client and the cookie as required, but still the cookie is not set in the browser
- Since this is a cross-origin request, a preflight `OPTIONS` request is sent first
- Current status:

**Preflight** request headers:

```
OPTIONS /api/v0/get_csrf_token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: app-version,authorization,os-type
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

**Preflight** response headers:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: app-version, authorization, os-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Vary: Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://rawgit.com; connect-src 'self' https://*.fontawesome.com; img-src 'self' data: https://*.amazonaws.com https://*.vizcloud.net https://*.viz.cloud; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://*.fontawesome.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://unpkg.com http://d3js.org https://rawgit.com https://*.fontawesome.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://rawgit.com https://*.fontawesome.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://rawgit.com; connect-src 'self' https://*.fontawesome.com; img-src 'self' data: https://*.amazonaws.com https://*.vizcloud.net https://*.viz.cloud; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://*.fontawesome.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://unpkg.com http://d3js.org https://rawgit.com https://*.fontawesome.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://rawgit.com https://*.fontawesome.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Length: 0
Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.7.9
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 09:06:31 GMT
```

**Follow-up `GET`** request headers:

```
GET /api/v0/get_csrf_token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Authorization: null
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
os-type: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
app-version: web
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: X-CSRFToken=IjI1ODlkZGQ4MzJlMzRiZDM2M2U5YzgyM2EyODAxNTgxZTIyNDYwOWYi.FMF7UQ.-do_q8Zv3Fonh5QdSvfhaGbAVBk
```

**Follow-up `GET`** response headers:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 3
/*** THIS IS THE COOKIE I NEED TO STORE ***/
Set-Cookie: X-CSRFToken=IjFhYmVkNjZmN2Y0NjEzMTNmNzRhNzI4ZGVlZTVmMzQzNTVjN2JmOTgi.FMF9Fw.DWGaapFRX40GwpV3KU07iHEZzKc; Expires=2022-01-13 12:06:31.906331; SameSite=None; Path=/; Secure
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Vary: Origin, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://rawgit.com; connect-src 'self' https://*.fontawesome.com; img-src 'self' data: https://*.amazonaws.com https://*.vizcloud.net https://*.viz.cloud; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://*.fontawesome.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://unpkg.com http://d3js.org https://rawgit.com https://*.fontawesome.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://rawgit.com https://*.fontawesome.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://rawgit.com; connect-src 'self' https://*.fontawesome.com; img-src 'self' data: https://*.amazonaws.com https://*.vizcloud.net https://*.viz.cloud; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://*.fontawesome.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://unpkg.com http://d3js.org https://rawgit.com https://*.fontawesome.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://rawgit.com https://*.fontawesome.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Set-Cookie: session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiMWFiZWQ2NmY3ZjQ2MTMxM2Y3NGE3MjhkZWVlNWYzNDM1NWM3YmY5OCJ9.FMF9Fw.r8g0VeK8PjVqEtWz6ZcJrVYg6fo; HttpOnly; Path=/
Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.7.9
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 09:06:31 GMT
```

Notice that the `X-CSRFToken` cookie in the `GET` response headers has `SameSite=None` and `Secure` attributes, as required for CORS.
But when I inspect DevTools in `Application -> Storage -> Cookies`, I see no cookies set in the browser.

You can also see the responses in the following images:

[preflight response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu0B2.png)

[`GET` response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rkcb.png)

What am I missing?

Comment: Check out the value of your cookie's `Expires` attribute: `2022-01-13 12:06:31.906331`. Because that date is in the past, the browser doesn't even set the cookie.

Comment: The `Expires` attribute in the above code is just an example, it was valid when I made the actual request.

Comment: @RonMichaeli Hello, have you come up with a valid solution yet?

Comment: @TheVisionary Not yet. Dropped it off for now...

Comment: @RonMichaeli I have the same problem (using ExpressJS). I have a client on domain.com and an auth server running on auth.domain.com . CORS set up correctly. Cookies set up correctly (I think) with HttpOnly, Secure, domain: .domain.com . I have simple, test endpoint that sets a cookie. When I send a request to auth.domain.com/test from my client (on domain.com) I get a nice response (so it is working) but no cookie is set. When I open the endpoint directly in my browser (auth.domain.com/test) I get a response and the cookie is set.. AND it is visible in the domain.com client!  ... grrrrrr