# How to set Cookie HTTP Only with .NET Core in client (Browser)

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, next.js, jwt

I'm trying to set Cookie HTTP Only to the client (Browser) using .NET Core and NextJS as front-end

The problem is when I made a request in postman the cookies are there
[Postman Token HTTP Only successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Jse.png)

So I don't need to send the token through the Authorization Bearer token, and I can made request to Apis which they need a valid token.

But I'm trying to handle in front-end but I can't set the Cookie Http only in browser
[Client(Browser Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpSeF.png)

as you can see the token is there but in Cookie Section the cookie is not available
[Browser Cookie Not Appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb4iL.png)

this is the code in Startup

```js
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new  JwtBearerEvents(){
                       OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
                        var cookies = request.Cookies;
                        if (cookies.TryGetValue("token", out var accessTokenValue))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessTokenValue;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(context.Token);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };                  
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
```

```js
 builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("myCors", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            //builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost");
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowCredentials();
        });
```

this is the configuration in method to Authenticate user and return token and setting a cookie

This is the request in Front-end

```js
     const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
         const result = await fetch(URL + 'Auth/Login', {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify(formValues)});
         console.log(result.status);
         if (result.status === 200) {
            const data = await result.json();
            console.log(data);
         }
      } catch (e) {}
   };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests)

Answer (score 0):

**AddJwtBearer** never deals with cookies and adding **.AddCookie()** in this example does not make any sense.

For **AddCookie()** to issue an cookie, then someone needs to signing the user and AddJwtBearer never does that.

But it is a bit unclear what you actually tries to achieve with that code.