# Set cookie from express.js via React.js won't set. (CORS is set up, credentials: 'include' is used)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie from my express backend via React frontend. The cookie is included in the response header but won't be set by the browser. I tested with Chromium and with Firefox, but had no luck. However in Postman it is setting the cookie perfectly fine.

I tried all suggestions I found here but none worked for me.

**Express** cookie options:

```js
exports.COOKIE_OPTIONS = {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    signed: true,
    maxAge: eval(process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRY) * 100,
    sameSite: 'Lax'
}
```

**Express** cors setup:

```js
const whitelist = process.env.WHITELISTED_DOMAINS

  ? process.env.WHITELISTED_DOMAINS.split(",")

  : []

const corsOptions = {

  origin: function (origin, callback) {

    if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {

      callback(null, true)

    } else {

      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"))

    }

  },

  credentials: true,

}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

With `WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = http://localhost:3000` in .env

**Express** response with cookie:

```js
res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, COOKIE_OPTIONS);
res.send({success: true, token});
```

**React** how I fetch:

```js
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT + "users/login", {
      method: "POST",
      credetials: "include",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
});
```

Everything else is working fine, e.g. the token in the body can be read.

#### Edit

I also tried it with following options which I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/12373756):
**Cookie Options**

```js
exports.COOKIE_OPTIONS = {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    signed: true,
    maxAge: eval(process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRY) * 100,
    SameSite: 'none'
}
```

***Response with cookie***

```js
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Custom-Header");
res.cookie("refreshToken", newRefreshToken, COOKIE_OPTIONS);
res.send({success: true, token});
```

But it wouldn't work either. Same result. Set-Cookie is present in the response but won't be stored.

**Pictures of the response:**
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs8D5.png)

[No cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQMGv.png)

Comment: how are you determining that the cookie isn't being set in the browser? using browser developer tools?

Comment: @Bravo Yes with the developer tools. Also my authentication won't work like intended without the cookie. So that's another clue.

Comment: just to get this straight in my head ... `Set-Cookie` response header does arrive at the browser, it's definitely a signed cookie, but no browser you've tried actually stores the cookie and therefore doesn't send it in subsequent requests

Comment: @Bravo Exactly. In the response header I receive the Set-Cookie with my refreshToken, Path, max-Age, etc. but it won't be stored. Neither with Firefox nor with Chromium. Also Chromium has no extensions at all and at Firefox are all extensions disabled for localhost. But Postman stores the Cookie just fine.

Comment: That is odd, I've never seen Firefox refuse to store a cookie without at least a warning in the developer tools console

Comment: @Bravo Yeah. I am pretty new to webdev so I can only rely on ressources I find. But I am now trying for hours over hours. But I get always the same result. There is also no warning. I added some screenshots. Maybe they give a clue?

Comment: by the way, the request is `localhost:8081` but you're inspecting cookies for `localhost:3000` - the other thing is, `Secure` cookies only work over `https`, and your request is over `http` - though, `localhost` can be considered "secure" in some cases (not sure about cookies though) - are you sure you haven't filtered `Warnings`  or any other log level in the console?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the sameSite option. Apparently this will handled differently as **S**ameSite. Using SameSite with capital "S" worked perfectly fine.

If someone can elaborate why this happens I would be glad.

Comment: I was just going to say that the cookie has no SameSite attribute in your picture ... since `sameSite` and `SameSite` are different strings, you'd expect that to make a difference .... but, where did you change sameSite to SameSite ... cookie options takes `sameSite` as a configuration property, not `SameSite`