# Cookie set on frontend does not appear in backend request on different domains

Tags: php, reactjs, cookies, http-headers, cross-domain

##### Context

Hello, I'm in a project where the backend (API) is separate from the frontend and I'm having problems with cookies in `cross-site`, I read some questions on Stackoverflow like this [set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests), but the solution didn't work for me.

##### Problem

The frontend is made in React and uses axios to perform the request and the [universal-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie) to set cookies, however in the production environment the cookie is not being sent through the request, while in the development environment where `Sec-Fetch-Site`  is `same site` (because both are on localhost), the cookie is successfully sent on the request.

The backend is made in PHP and makes use of a [middleware cors lib](https://github.com/tuupola/cors-middleware) to handle CORS.

###### Request that does not send the cookie

[image]

[image: Storage - cookie does not working]

###### Request that correctly sends the cookie

[image: Request - cookie is working]

[image: Storage - cookie is working]

##### Tests

Assuming the frontend is on the `frontend.com` domain and the backend on `backend.com`, I made the following changes I found on the internet and it didn't work:

- I configured the backend to return in its response header

  - `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and
  - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://frontend.com` and
  - `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization`
- I configured axios on the frontend with `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`
- On the frontend I set the cookie with the `same-site: none`, `secure: true` and `path: /`

`Note 01`: The cookie is visible in the browser's storage, but in the request it is not sent.

`Note 02`: The only thing I noticed in the request that works for the request that doesn't work even though both have the cookie stored in the browser's storage is that in the request that the cookie does not appear in the request, the `Sec-Fetch-Site` header is the same to `cross-site`, while in the request that works the `Sec-Fetch-Site` header is equal to `same-site`.

Comment: Cookie are not send for different domains than the one they were set for, and no CORS or other settings will change that.

Comment: @CBroe in my use case, where I need the client to send the cookie value in every request for the backend (api) to use that value, do you think using a custom header (`X-Endpoint`) would be a good approach?

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? @IgorAC

Comment: @HussamKhatib yes, I had to use custom headers instead of the cookie.