# HttpOnly cookie is not set in Chrome using FastAPI

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, next.js, fastapi

I have an api built in FastAPI running on `localhost:8000` and a NextJS frontend running on `localhost:3000`. I'm using `HttpOnly` cookie to store the JWT token after user authentication. But for some reason the cookie is not set in chrome and subsequent requests are not authenticated. When I test the mechanism in insomnia it is working, but on the frontend it doesn't. Here is my actual setup.

The login endpoint:

```py
@router.post("/signin", response_model=SigninResponseSchema)
def sign_in(
    response: Response,
    *,
    user_credentials: SigninSchema,
    db: Session = Depends(database.get_db),
) -> any:
    signin_infos = auth_service.authenticate_user(db, user_credentials=user_credentials)
    sign_in_response = SigninResponseSchema(
        status="successful", 
        access_token=signin_infos["access_token"],
        user_data=signin_infos["user_data"],
        user_roles=signin_infos["user_roles"]
    )
    token = jsonable_encoder(sign_in_response.access_token)
    response.set_cookie(
        "Authorization",
        value=f"Bearer {token}",
        httponly=True,
        secure=True,
        samesite="none",
        max_age=1800,
        expires=1800,
    )
    return sign_in_response
```

The cors setup:

```py
origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000" 
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
    allow_headers=["Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Set-Cookie"],
)
```

How do I solve the problem? I've already taken a look to several solutions on the internet but none of them is working. What could be the problem ?

Comment: maybe setting path on set_cookie will fix the problem

Comment: Please note that you have set the `secure` flag to `True`, meaning that the cookie will only be sent if the request is made using the HTTPS protocol, which you don't seem to be using (see [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#set-cookie)). On a side note, I would not suggest using `samesite="none"`, unless you are creating [cross-domain cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) and you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup on the FastAPI side looks good, the issue is likely in your front-end application.

One thing that jumps out is that you're making your requests from `http://localhost:3000` which isn't over HTTPS, and you're setting your cookie with `secure=True`.  Ideally you should be running your front-end app locally over HTTPS and making requests from `https://localhost:3000`.

Here's a couple more things to check on the client side:

- In your request, make sure you've set the [XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) flag to true (this was my problem), this can be achieved in different ways depending on the request-response library used:

  - jQuery 1.5.1 xhrFields: `{withCredentials: true}`
  - ES6 fetch(): `credentials: 'include'`
  - axios: `withCredentials: true`
- Your request headers should include `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000"`

Credit: [This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/4122385) got me unstuck from a similar issue