# Cross-Domain App Authentication to HTTP API Server

Tags: authentication, cookies, cors, cross-domain

I am attempting to set CORS headers on my API server (`myserver.com`) to allow cross-origin, authenticated requests with cookies from my embedded mobile app or other site (`localhost:8080`)

Here is the initial request, which appears to be working properly and sets the right cookie.

```
Summary
URL: https://myserver.com/api/tokens
Status: 200
Source: Network
Address: 1.1.1.1:443

Request
:method: POST
:scheme: https
:authority: myserver.com
:path: /api/tokens
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Content-Length: 51
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Host: myserver.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Safari/605.1.15
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

Response
:status: 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: token=removedforsecuritypurposes; path=/; expires=Tue, 02 Aug 2022 03:57:50 GMT; samesite=none; secure; httponly
Vary: Origin
Date: Sun, 03 Jul 2022 03:57:50 GMT
Content-Length: 616
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Server: nginx/1.14.1
```

I'm using `axios` on the frontend, using the `withCredentials: true` option to send subsequent requests, but the browser doesn't include the cookie. What am I missing?

```
Summary
URL: https://myserver.com/api/user
Status: 401
Source: Network
Address: 1.1.1.1:443

Request
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:authority: myserver.com
:path: /api/user
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: myserver.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Connection: keep-alive

Response
:status: 401
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Vary: Origin
Date: Sun, 03 Jul 2022 03:57:50 GMT
Content-Length: 134
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Server: nginx/1.14.1
```

I've referenced this post [Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437) and still can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Allow `localhost` as origin in your CORS settings on your server.
2. Use a Capacitor plugin (e.g. [`@capacitor-community/http`](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http)) to send HTTP requests natively ( CORS is ignored here).

Comment: Could you explain option 1 in more depth? I’ve tried adding the ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header, which allows the request to go through, but my server sends back ‘HTTP 401’ because the cookies are not included.

Comment: I don't know what framework you are using server side, for Nest for example you would do it this way: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors

Comment: Cookies are a different problem, but for CORS you only have these two options.

Comment: I recommend the Capacitor plugin, it also gives you small performance benefits on native platforms.