# How can I share a cross site cookie?

Tags: php

I have the following code on example1.com:

```
<?php
setcookie('_ch' , base64_encode($file) , time() + (60) , '/');
header("Location: http://example2.com/");
exit();
```

And on example2.com:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['_ch'])){
    echo error::noocookie();
    exit();
}
```

The problem I face is that the `if` statement is always true. How can I access the cookie from example2.com?

Comment: This may help you look at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests

Comment: @Eggz thanks. JSON is also an option here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A website isn't allowed to set cookies for other domains.

See [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3). Specifically point 6 of the storage model section.

> If the canonicalized request-host does not domain-match the
> domain-attribute:
> Ignore the cookie entirely and abort these steps.

and [the domain-match section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3):

> A string domain-matches a given domain string if at least one of
> the    following conditions hold:
>
> - The domain string and the string are identical.  (Note that both
>   the domain string and the string will have been canonicalized to
>   lower case at this point.)
> - All of the following conditions hold:
>
>   - The domain string is a suffix of the string.
>   - The last character of the string that is not included in the
>     domain string is a %x2E (".") character.
>   - The string is a host name (i.e., not an IP address).

With a domain of `example2.com` and a request-host of `example1.com`, none of these conditions are true.

Comment: What can I do instead to confirm that the user visited example1.com before example2.com with an expiration of this confirmation?

Comment: Redirect the user from 1 to 2 with a token that can verify them (e.g. a GUID that 2 makes a server-side HTTP request back to 1 to auth or something like a JWT)