# PHP API - Cookies are sent, not saved in browser

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers, httpcookie

I have a problem with cookies.

I have a simple (self created) REST API in PHP, running on localhost:80/api.

FrontEnd is React App running localhost:3456.

In PHP the cookie header is:

```
"Set-Cookie: jwt_refresh_token=".$jwtRefreshToken."; HttpOnly ; Max-Age=3600; Secure; SameSite=None;"
```

The cookie is actualy send to client, but it is not saved in browser

Recieved cookie, edge
[image: Recieved cookie, edge]

Other PHP headers which are sent to clients:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3456');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

What I tried and it didnt help, after reading tons of Questions, answers and tutorials:

1. Turn of cookie SECURE param, while its localhost
2. Use IP, instad of localhost
3. Push API online and use SSL
4. Run client app on URL without port, directly on localhost (etc->localhost:80)

PS: Everything is working when testing API in postman -> cookie is automaticly saved in Postmans cookies.

Anyone know, what to do?

**Update 1**

Response headers [image: REsponse]

Request headers [image: REquest]

Preflight Response
[image: Response - prelight]

Preflight Request
[image: Request]

**Update 2**
Okay, regarding to other posts - Edge, Chrome (and other chrome core browsers) they dont want to save cookies, on pages which have a port number (As my frontend runs at localhost:3456), tried again localhost(:80) and it works now for FireFox atleast. But still not for chrome core browser

Comment: This is a wild guess, but have you tried adding Cookie to the list of allowed headers?

Comment: @rickdenhaan if you mean the Access-Control-Allow-Headers, that refers to what _request_ headers are permitted, nothing to do with what the server returns back.

Comment: @Bartas please show how you're making the request to this endpoint from the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests)

Comment: @ADyson Actualy no, I read this before and as I think I have everything as its suggested in that post

Comment: @ADyson Updated my post, there are screens of request, response and prelight request and response

Comment: @rickdenhaan Tried, but as mentioned by ADyson nothing to do with that = doesnt help