# Problem with setting cookies on localhost during development

Tags: vue.js, express, cookies, localhost, vite

I have **nodejs** **express** app as backend, and **vue** app as frontend on my server. I use session cookies for authentication and i just can't get them working on my local dev machine. **Cookie is sent in the response but it is not saved by browser**. I know that problem is that request origin must be same as host and i have read all the articles/questions related to the issue and i just can't solve it.

On the server, everything is proxied with nginx on https. Cookie is set there and everything works fine, because they are on same host.

My local **vite** dev server is running on https, on port 5173.

I use axios for api calls and i have set

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Cookie properties are

```
sameSite:'none', 
secure:true,
httpOnly:true,
```

In express:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['https://localhost:5173', 'https://my.site.com'],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

Like i said before, cookie is sent in the response from the server and just not stored on browser because in request header:

```
host:my.site.com
origin:https://localhost:5173
referer:https://localhost:5173/
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed solution in comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/13781306.
It partialy works when i set

```
sameSite:'none', 
secure:false,
```

Cookie is passed in requests but it is not stored in the browser storage/cookies. Which is fine and solves my issue.