# I get the cookie from backend, but it is not set in frontend why?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, cors, session-cookies

I am using expressjs for backend and vitejs for frontend.
here is my code of backend :

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true, withCredentials: true }))
app.use(cookieParser());
```

```
db.query("COMMIT", (err) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);

            const token = createToken(data[0].id, null);
            const { password, ...other } = data[0];
            return res.cookie("access_token", token, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true }).status(200).json(other);
          });
```

frontend code:

```
      await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/user/signup", inputs, { withCredentials: true })
```

I have tried different browser but it still not working.

Comment: what! sorry i didn't get it, can you elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different frontend and backend servers (with different hostnames, not just different ports) and the HTML/Javascript served by the frontend server wants to make an HTTP request with cookies to the backend server, this cannot work, because:

- Cookies from the backend count as "cross-site" in a request made from the frontend server's page. Such cookies are only sent if they have [`SameSite=None`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite).
- Cookies with `SameSite=None` must also have the `Secure` attribute and are then only sent over HTTPS connections.

What you could do:

- In your development environment, use HTTP, cookies without `SameSite` or `Secure` attributes and have frontend and backend servers both on `localhost`, just on different ports.
- In the production environment, use HTTPS for both frontend and backend servers, cookies with `SameSite=None; Secure`.

Comment: Can you suggest me any documentation or code that can help me. I have already tried with only httpOnly: true.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie

Comment: This does not appear to be quite right. I have both backend and frontend running on different ports @localhost but am running into this same issue. As I understood it, even differing ports count as _cross-domain_. I think the solution might be `SameSite=None + Secure + HTTPS` .. or apparently just by putting the cookies in your response body and _creating_ them in your FE. This latter option seems more like a workaround to me. I would love to be wrong here, but I've been trying to solve this for about a day or so now and this is what I have come up with.

Comment: @sherrellbc read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/4800344 and the comments for it