# How do I resolve SameSite issues when requesting a wms/image from geoserver?

Tags: html, gis, geoserver, wms, samesite

I have an html file where I made a request of a wms/image from my geoserver instance using the image tag. When I open the html file in Chrome browser, on the web page, a broken image icon is shown where the expected wms/image is expected.

When I paste only the src link of the image tab in the html file in the address bar of the Chrome browser I get the expected wms/image from the geoserver properly dispalyed.

I have tried requesting same wms/image from my geoserver instance on my localhost and also my geoserver instance on the cloud hosted by AcuGIS.

My geoserver instance version 2.17.0

The error on inspection in the Chrome browser is a SameSite issue.

My code below:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Leaflet WMS working</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>


        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #map {
                height: 80%;
                width: 100vw;
            }
            #input {
                width:100vw;
                height:20%;
                background-color:beige;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='map'></div>
        <div id='input'>
            <img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=dj:dj_raptor"> 
        </div>

        <script>
            var map = L.map('map').setView([40.1, -104.8], 11);
            L.control.scale().addTo(map);

            var lyrOSM = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 19,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'})
            lyrOSM.addTo(map);            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error I get in the browser below:

```
Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests.
1 cookie
Name    Domain & Path
JSESSIONID  localhost/geoserver
1 request
 png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=dj:dj_raptor
```

[image: Error I get in the browser]

I have read many things about SameSite but how to apply a solution to geoserver is not clear to me. I have been at resolving this issue for about 2 months now and no progress. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob thank you for the info. I have added to the question the error texts same as in the error image.

Comment: Can you share the code from your geoserver that sets the cookie? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343715/i-get-the-cookie-from-backend-but-it-is-not-set-in-frontend-why

Comment: @HeikoTheißen could you point me to a particular file / file name on my geoserver instance where geoserver sets the cookies? There are a number of files here that I have been going through on my geoserver but nothing suggests to be the one with respect to setting of cookies. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how geoserver works internally. I thought you would.