# Cookies are not stored in the browser

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, nestjs

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now. I'm trying to log into my application and I can't set cookies in the browser. I am using Google Chrome Version 117.0.5938.150 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I am using node with nestjs on the back end, this is my code:

auth.controller

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)   
@Get('profile')   
getProfile(@Req() req) {     
return req.user;   
}
```

JwtStrategy

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
constructor() {
super({
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors(\[
JwtStrategy.extractJWTFromCookie,
\]),
ignoreExpiration: false,
secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY
});
}

private static extractJWTFromCookie(req: Request): string | null {
if (req.cookies && req.cookies.access_token) {
return req.cookies.access_token;
}
return null;
}

async validate(payload: UserJwtPayload) {
return {
userId: payload.sub,
username: payload.username,
role: payload.role,
};
}
}
```

Here I´m enabling cookie parse and cors

```
app.use(cookieParser())

app.enableCors({
origin: process.env.DISPOSITIVO_UI_ADDRESS,
methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Accept',
credentials: true
})
```

and this is the front-end request

```
await axios.get(PROFILE_USER_URL, {       
withCredentials: true     
})
```

The funny thing about this is that this works when I'm testing it in Postman, so maybe it's a browser issue? I'm not sure:

[image: Postman test]

I am in fact Setting-Cookie in the server response, but it is not stored in the storage cookie:

[image: Loggin]

I trust the code I did, Postman confirm it. So if it's not a code problem, it's not about how it's written, what's the problem here? I really don't understand what's going on.

I try to set:

```
httpOnly = false
sameSite = 'none'
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get the cookie from backend, but it is not set in frontend why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343715/i-get-the-cookie-from-backend-but-it-is-not-set-in-frontend-why)

Comment: I have tried all the solutions there, none of them worked.