# I have an issue where the browser is not storing or sending the cookie after reciving it (reactJS/expressJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, cors

"I'm encountering an issue where a cookie for authentication is being sent, but the browser fails to save it, resulting in a CORS error stating 'no allow credentials'. Here are my Express CORS settings:

javascript

```
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000','http://192.168.1.39:3000','http://localhost:3001']
}));
```

And here are the cookie settings:

javascript

```
res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: false, 
    sameSite: 'None',
    secure: false,
    maxAge:60*60*1000, // 1 hour
});
```

The received cookie and headers are shown in the following images:
[cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEz1G.png)
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE84E.png)
I'm sending a login request to receive the cookie using Axios:

javascript

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000',
  // withCredentials: true, // Include credentials (cookies) in cross-origin requests
});
```

```
export const login = async (email, password, authLogin) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post('/users/login', {
      email,
      password,
    });
    const { accessToken } = response.data;
    sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
    console.log("The tokens are set :", sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Login failed:', error);
    return false;
  }
};
```

However, the request to fetch the token encounters a CORS error ('cors no allow credentials'):
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yERK.png)

I've tried various solutions from other posts, such as changing 'secure' to false and 'sameSite' to None, but nothing seems to work. Testing with Postman shows that my APIs are functioning correctly."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get the cookie from backend, but it is not set in frontend why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343715/i-get-the-cookie-from-backend-but-it-is-not-set-in-frontend-why)