# Third party Cookie is not visible under browser's application/cookies

Tags: cookies, browser, cors, cross-domain, session-cookies

From domain "origin.a.com" , an ajax call is being made to a servlet on another domain "cms.b.com" to fetch some response and show on the page hosted on origin.a.com. For tracking purpose, cms.b.com is maintaining a cookie and sending along with the response, but the cookie is not visible in browser->application/cookies under origin.a.com. However, the cookie can be seen in set-cookie (response header). Using CORS, trying to establish the calls and cookie.

Below is the configuration used.

code on https://origin.a.com

```
    $.ajax({
       url: "https://cms.b.com/content/endpoint/Data",     
       type: "POST",   
       CORS: "true",
       xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
       },
       crossDomain: true,
       contentType: "text/plain",
       data: JSON.stringify({ rootPagePath:"/content/a/b/en/08", uid: "w47fh4fhj" }),
       success: function (result) {
       console.log("successful call");
      },
      error: function (err) {
      console.log("unsuccessful call")
     }
    });
```

Response header and cookie on https://cms.b.com servlet

```
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://origin.a.com");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,      Authorization");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  

    String cookieValue3  = "devCookie="+userSession.getId()+";"+"Path="+"/;"+"SameSite=None; Secure;"+"max-age=500;";

    response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookieValue3);
```

The cookie is available in response header
[cookie in response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0k9h.png)

The cookie is not being available under application/ cookies for domain "https://origin.a.com ". What is being missed to support CORS calls and maintain cookie from another domain under requested domain ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests)