# Browser is not sending the cookie with fetch after successful login

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, cors, header

no matter what I try the browser refuses to send the cookie with additional requests after successful login.

I use `fetch(url, { credentials: "include"})`, I set the cors headers in the response like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
Content-Type, Authorization, Set-Cookie, Cookie, Origin, X-Dev-Token, Bearer, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
https://mydomain.de

Set-Cookie:
token=eyJhbG34SAmOgmnfmvjBP6OfhwVyftgHnc; Secure; SameSite=None, HttpOnly; Max-Age=432000
```

So this is a https site, both front- and backend are controlled by me, they just have different domains.

So what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are the additional requests sent to the same back-end domain? Cookies are only sent to the same domain that sent it.

Comment: Do you see the cookie in Developer Tools in the browser?

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests @Barmar

Comment: "http is not same as https in CORS" from the answer linked. Perhaps this?

Comment: You have a typo in your `Set-Cookie` header: a comma separates `SameSite=None` and `HttpOnly`, but [the only separator allowed is the semicolon](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1). Also, you can safely drop the following header names from `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`: [`Cookie`, `Origin`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header), and [`Set-Cookie`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name). Finally, consider using a proven CORS middleware library rather than implementing CORS "by hand", as doing so is error-prone.

Comment: @jub0bs thanks for pointing out the typo. I fixed the typo but still the same problem.

I see the Set-Cookie in the response header, but there are no cookie sent with the following requests that need authentication. Both domains have valid https, login and api is the same server and domain.

I cant use any middleware (and dont want to) since I am running a native bun server :D

Comment: @Barmar I can't see the cookie inside the application tab.